# SXA location filter by radius as 0 miles is showing zero results

Tags: sxa

I am using SXA 1.8.1 and Sitecore 9.0.2

For my application i want to show list of properties in a given area.
I followed [this](https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2016/10/build-location-finder-search-using-sxa.html) link (Michael West's blog).

I have a radius filter as 0miles, 5 miles, 10 miles.
When i enter a location in location finder and select 0miles, i get the result count as 0, even though i have a property in the given location.

the hash getting formed is -

```
#rent-search-result_g=51.515973|-0.17494299999998475&rent-search-result_o=Distance%2CAscending&rent-search-result_a=Paddington%2C%20London%2C%20UK&rent-search-result_distance=0
```

in the hash url geolocation of selected location is added and for radius 0 miles distance value is 0, so its basically searching the property at selected geolocation itself.

I want to show properties in the entered area if 0 miles is selected, which means properties with in that area. when 5 miles is selected the properties under the radius of the selected area and +5 miles from the area should be listed.

or to list properties under a selected postcode when no radius filter is selected.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using 0as the radius option as it will basically mean that you want to search POIs in the circle of radius 0. Increase it a little bit and you should see some results.